# Command 'celeryd' not known when using ckanext-archiver

Tags: celery, ckan, celeryd

I'm using CKAN as my open data portal and am installing the Archiver Extension by following the instructions at https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-archiver. I have installed celery as shown:

```
Successfully installed celery kombu kombu-sqlalchemy messytables flask anyjson amqplib xlrd python-magic chardet json-table-schema lxml Werkzeug
```

But I am unable to run it.

```
/usr/lib/ckan/default/src$ paster celeryd -c /etc/ckan/default

Command 'celeryd' not known (you may need to run setup.py egg_info)
Known commands:
  create       Create the file layout for a Python distribution
  exe          Run #! executable files
  help         Display help
  make-config  Install a package and create a fresh config file/directory
  points       Show information about entry points
  post         Run a request for the described application
  request      Run a request for the described application
  serve        Serve the described application
  setup-app    Setup an application, given a config file
```

My CKAN root directory: usr/lib/ckan/default/src
path to ckan config file: /etc/ckan/default

Hope someone can help solve my issue. Thanks.

Comment: Did you activate your virtual environment before running the paster command? It should something like `. /usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/activate` (keep the preceding dot - it's important!), then `paster` will be able to find the celery package in the correct `site-packages`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No module named celery when installing ckanext-archiver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24113057/no-module-named-celery-when-installing-ckanext-archiver)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late answer but you need to be in /usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan context in order to perform the command.